# Search and print result from multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 3 tables. service_robot_errorservice contains a foreign key that is primary key in the service table. robot_error does not have ore give any foreign keys.

```
TABLE: robot_error
| id | date | stop_time | start_time | robot | position | error_code | observation | solution | downtime | logged_by |
| 1 | 02.01.2012 | 14:51:31 | 14:52:00 | 20 | 25/7 | 214 | X dir | Rob off | 29 | XXX |

TABLE: service
| service_id | service_date | service_module | service_user | service_comment | service_type |
| 1 | 13.01.2012 | Robot | XXX | Test service | Errorservice |

TABLE: service_robot_errorservice
| errorservice_id | service_id | errorservice_robot | errorservice_tracksensor | errorservice_gripper |
| 5 | 1 | 54 | OK | OK |
```

When a user searches for a robot (eks 16) i want the result to be every instance in robot_error orderd by date AND if the robot has service registered this instance should also be shown in the result.

Example:

```
robot_error instance
robot_error instance
robot_error instance
service instance
robot_error instance
service instance
```

That is what i want the result to look. I've tryed to first get the result out of this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM robot_error WHERE robot = '16'
```

and make a while to loop all results in robot_error table but i cant figure out how i can make the result from service tables to be shown, can anyone help? :)

Comment: So you want to find all the records in `robot_error` for a robot with a particular `id` and a single record from `service` if that robot has a service associated with it? In the `service_robot_errorservice` table, is `errorservice_robot` the `id` of the robot?

Comment: and a single record from service if that robot has a service associated with it? This does not have to be a single it can be 0 to many. errorservice_robot is the id of the robot, yes. It is the same id used in robot_error. robot = errorservice_robot

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [joins](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

- JOIN: Return rows when there is at least one match in both tables
- LEFT JOIN: Return all rows from the left table, even if there are no matches in the right table
- RIGHT JOIN: Return all rows from the right table, even if there are no matches in the left table
- FULL JOIN: Return rows when there is a match in one of the tables

But you'd have to have a relation between robot_error and service before you can use a query with a join. It would probably look something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM robot_error LEFT OUTER JOIN services ON robot_error.ID = services.FK WHERE robot = '16'
```

[Jeff Atwood demonstrates the different Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) quite nicley

Comment: I dont think that i can use join beacuse i get this result:
robot_error xxx | service_id 1
robot_error xxx | service_id 1

if there is 16 robot_errors on that robot, the join will make 16 instances from service tables. There can be 16 errors but only 1 service. there can also be 1 error and 5 services. Here is an image to illustrate
http://bildr.no/view/1076987

Comment: The result - means there was nothing to join with. This is by design and implies that either the query's wrong or the relation of the datasets. As mentioned the robot_error and service tables must have a relation for this to work. I used robot_error.ID and service.FK as placeholders you'd have to implement the relation yourself. You can also just play with the query and check what results you get, eventually you'll figure it out.

Comment: I'm quite sure this setup is not [normalized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization). However I think the table service_robot_errorservice holds the key ;). If both the ID of robot_error and service are in that table you can use a query to get the information you want. Something like this: SELECT * FROM service_robot_errorservice LEFT OUTER JOIN robot_error ON service_robot_errorservice.errorservice_robot = error_robot.id LEFT OUTER JOIN service ON service_robot_errorservice.service_id = service.service_id WHERE robot_error.robot = '16' this is from the head so check it

Comment: Hmm, but there is not any connection between robot_error and service. Service can be preformed if the robot does not have any errors registerd. And i dont want to connect a service to a spesific error. Is there any way i can make this happen by using multiple queries and sort it in PHP?

Comment: I understand what the result should be but I can't understand your tables. You need some kind of relation from the service table to a robot. The Information you've given indicates there is no way of telling what robot was serviced, except maybe with the table service_robot_errorservice (see my previous comment). Please explain how you map the errors and services to a robot and what the table service_robot_errorservice is for.